# C++/CLI, XAML, and event handlers

Tags: wpf, xaml, event-handling, c++-cli

I'm new to the Windows world, and I think I'm getting lost in the weeds on a problem. I'd love some advice from people with experience with C++/CLI and WPF and XAML.

I have some win32 code, and I need to run a WPF GUI. I found [this MS walkthrough sample, which uses C++/CLI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970266.aspx). I adapted it to my purposes, and it works great.

Next, I wanted to rip out the programmatic WPF stuff and use XAML instead. This is so I can hand off the XAML to a designer person and take myself out of the UI design loop, where I most assuredly don't belong. After reading the "WPF Interoperation Projects" section of [WPF and Win32 Interoperation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522.aspx), I decided to go with the `XamlReader::Load` option and load uncompiled XAML at runtime. My XAML markup is a `Canvas` `UIElement` which I programmatically add as a child of my root `Grid` C++/CLI element. This works great.

Now I want to add event handler to controls in the XAML. This is where I have started to run into trouble. I'm sure that my general ignorance of the Windows world is 95% of what's killing me here.

I started with [Rob Relyea's page outlining the various XAML-and-event-handler options](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea/archive/2009/06/03/xaml-events-in-compiled-and-uncompiled-scenarios.aspx).

I decided to try compiling the XAML as a C# DLL. It's basically the same XAML as what I used in the runtime Load case. I instantiate the object and programmatically add as it as a child, just like before. But ... I get nothing but a black window. No exceptions get thrown either. I'm baffled.

My question is, am I even headed down the right path? The page on XAML-and-event-handlers says you can use event handlers defined in uncompiled XAML in .Net Framework 4. Should I bite the bullet and just go to VS 2010 (I'm presently on VS 2008) so I can use .Net Framework 4 and just stick with uncompiled XAML? Are there any gotchas with doing things that way?

Or, if you do think the compiled C# DLL is a reasonable path, do you have any ideas on how I can debug the problems I'm having?

Or, is there a better and completely different approach?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Polly

Comment: You're on the wrong path.  Tooling is pretty important in WPF, whether through the IDE or Expression.  There is no tooling integration with C++/CLI whatsoever.  And there never will be.  Nor is there any advantage to using C++/CLI over C#.

Comment: Hans, thanks for your comment. I generally favor the well-trod path (i.e., C# over C++/CLI) too, but in this case there's a considerable investment in C++ code I need to preserve. In this case, my goal is to give that existing code a much prettier face.

Comment: Unmanaged code can call managed code quite easily via C++/CLI, so you could write your GUI in C# but have it called by C++ code.  While it is more usual to have C# call C++ via C++/CLI, your approach is just as valid.  If you don't want to use C# you'll have to assign event handlers in code-behind with some tricky calls like FindName or searching the visual tree.  It can be done, but I think you'd have less pain making C# assemblies for use by your C++ code.

Answer (score 3):

I think the right answer for this depends on some issues that only you can decide, but I'll start with the assumption that your C++ code base is big and complex enough that it is worth preserving.

Beyond that the next decision point is do you have UI (perhaps GDI) code in the C++ your preserving or only non-UI code.  If you are attempting to preserve only non-UI code then I would consider pushing more UI responsibilty into C#.  Perhaps you go so far as to build your views, event handlers, and maybe even view models in C#.  This will enable you to take better advantage of the VS tooling.

If you've got extensive UI code in C++ to preserve then your current path makes a more sense. I don't think it will be impossible, but you'll have quite a challenge ahead of you.  The key example here is Visual Studio 2010.  It is the premiere example of a mixed application and has GDI and WPF side by side unlike any other app I've ever seen or heard of.  There is a series of blog posts that I found pretty interesting that describe some aspects of what the Visual Studio team did to achieve this integration at [The Visual Studio Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/02/16/wpf-in-visual-studio-2010-part-1.aspx).

I also came across this video [Henry Sowizral on Refacing C++ with WPF in Expression Design](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Psychlist1972/Henry-Sowizral-on-Refacing-C-with-WPF-in-Expression-Design) that I have not seen myself, but discusses putting a WPF UI on top of an existing MFC C++ app.

Good luck.

I don't have any specific advice on the first part of your question other than to say that putting more responsibility in C# would allow you to build a small stub app if necessary which could go a long way toward diagnosing problems.

Comment: These are all good points. In this case, though, I have some large amount of performance-sensitive code in C++ that I want to give it a more attractive WPF GUI. The GUI code is not at all performance-sensitive. The performance reasons are why I decided to have a C++ app that calls into WPF code for occasional GUI purposes, rather than a C# app that calls into C++ code for long computation. I'll admit, though, that was based on intuition and not a thorough knowledge of win32/.Net interoperability performance considerations. Do you think I have that wrong? Thx for the pointers; I'll have a look.

Comment: It's really hard to be any more specific based on the information here.  I was thinking that you could create a ViewModel (search MVVM); it's basically a data model of what you want to display in your Xaml.  Then bind your Xaml to the C# ViewModel then manipulate or respond to the ViewModel in C++.  This would keep the Xaml stuff more traditional and blendable.  I don't know if putting a ViewModel in C++ would be possible.  There is a mismatch for the Xaml vs Win32 methodology in addition to the language issue.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to everyone for the responses. On the matter of getting stuck on the C# DLL, I found this C++/CLI sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970266.aspx. Using that, I found my error, and was able to load the WPF without problems.

However, the whole motivation for loading the C# DLL was that I had understood that that was the way to attach event handlers programmatically. Following AresAvatar's suggestion, I found that I could use FindName to attach the handlers -- both within the C# DLL, but it also worked with my original loose-XAML approach. So, I didn't need the C# DLL after all!

It's all working nicely now. Again, thanks for all of your help and suggestions.